# chart.js show no charts in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

chart.js Version 2.5.0

It works fine in Google Chrome, but not in IE11. There is no charts shown.
Whats wrong?

```
<canvas id="ks2" width="500" height="500"></canvas>   
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("ks2");
    var ks2 = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
        data: {
        labels: ["KS2 (1)", "KS2 (2)", "Differenz"],
            datasets: [{
            label: 'KS2',
            data: [25, 35, 10, 0]
            }]
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `meta tag` as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```